# how to calculate items sold in excel?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a list of sales of my company in Excel file and I need to find how many items we have sold.

I want Excel to count the filled rows in a sheet and tell me how many cells have been 
filled.

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. By looking at the two questions you have asked so far, it would be of great benefit for you to read ***[ask]*** and update your questions with more detail of what you have attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use COUNTA which counts non-blank cells in a range.

Comment: Tnx man, it was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the function COUNTIF

The syntax is simple:

```
 COUNTIF(range, criteria)
```

For example to find all non-blank cells in the range C1:C20 it will be:

```
=COUNTIF(C1:C20,"<>"&"")
```